How to prove a series of differential forms is well-defined?
I'm reading Fangyang Zheng's Complex Differential Geometry. I have a problem  while reading the following statement.

Fix a complex manifold $M^{n}$. Denote by $\mathcal{V}$ the Hilbert space of global holomorphic $n$-forms $\varphi$ (i.e. $\varphi$ is an $(n,0)$-form and $\overline\partial\varphi=0$) on $M$ that are $L^{2}$, i.e.,
$$\int_{M} \varphi \wedge \overline{\varphi}<\infty.$$
Let $\left\{\varphi_{1}, \varphi_{2}, \cdots\right\}$ be a unitary basis of $\mathcal{V}$. Clearly, the $(n, n)$-form on $M$
$$K(z, \bar{z})=i^{n^{2}} \sum_{\alpha} \varphi_{\alpha}(z) \wedge \overline{\varphi_{\alpha}(z)}$$
is well-defined and is independent of the choice of the unitary basis. It is called the Bergman kernel form of $M^{n}$.

This is the first time I have seen series of differential forms. I have no idea about its well-definiteness. Any help would be appreciated!

see Prop 3.10 in https://services.phaidra.univie.ac.at/api/object/o:1333741/get
